# Calling drawing on JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've got a class in which there is a method that draws rectangles on a JFrame. Furthermore I've got a few methods with different types of sorting. In those sorting methods I am calling the drawing method when a specified button is clicked. I would like my code to be cleaner, so I wanted to divide the class into one that is responsible for drawing things and the other one that does the sorting. I don't know how I can call the drawing method from outside the class. I wanted to use static, but I would have to make all the variables inside the method static. I also thought about making an inner class, but I will still have that one big class and it doesn't really help. What can I do?

Comment: Make an instance of your class with `new` and call the methods on that instance?

Comment: Create a model, use an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to facilitate communications between the model and the view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only be drawing from within the paintComponents method of the container. So it doesn't make sense for some external code to initiate a call to draw stuff. If you want this external class to change what is drawn, it should pass a reference to an object implementing some understood interface that can be called by the paintComponents method.

Comment: Thank you! I knew about the paintComponents (I need to read a little bit more about it though), but the second part of your answer helped me get an idea of what to exactly do.